# count queries in cassandra with solr index

Tags: solr, cassandra

I have a requirement to get certain counts from my table, in cassandra. What I understood is its not a good idea to run count queries in cassandra as it scans all the nodes. We already have solr indexes enabled for few tables in cassandra, and I was trying to use this feature to run my count queries. After looking on the web, found this article https://www.datastax.com/blog/running-count-expensive-cassandra, which also mentions Solr a possible solution to perform count queries.

Is it ok to run count using solr indexes on my cassandra table. Something like this

select count(1) from employee where solr_query='{"q": "employee_department:HR"}'   // just a random example

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't count the results in that manner with Solr. What you need to look at is the document count after you've run your query.

Otherwise, the most efficient way to count records in Cassandra is by using the [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) (DSBulk) tool. Here are some references that you will find helpful:

- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Doc - [More examples of counting data with DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkCountExamples.html)
- Answered questions - [DS Community](https://community.datastax.com/topics/dsbulk.html)

DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Comment: Can you please point me to the right count approach for Cassandra solr.